# Hydrolysis under basic medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrolysis, esters

[image]

The first compound is said to be hydrolyzed more easily than the 2nd compound below under Alkaline medium . How is this possible ?

I thought due to resonance, -NO2 acquires negative charge which faces repulsion from the solvation effect by basic medium. But it will be relatively easier for oxygen in -CH3O( in 2nd compound) to donate its electrons to have it in resonance with benzene. But this contradicts with answer. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the mechanism of hydrolysis under basic medium, the lone pair of hydroxide ion will attack on C=O carbon.

Due to the negative mesomeric (-M/-R) effect and negative inductive effect of the nitro group, the C=O will act as a more electrophilic substrate as compared to the one which is has ether substituent,

(which due to its +M and +I effect will reduce the electrophilic character of the C=O ),
will be easier to hydrolyse.

The effect of solvation on substituents is less likely to tell which compound will hydrolyse easily as it is not the [Rate Determining Step](//www.google.com/search?q=rate+determining+step+of+nucleophilic+addition+elimination&oq=rate+determining+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0l2.6387j0j7&client=ms-android-oneplus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) of the reaction. So although the observation is not wrong, its still not the deciding factor.

Comment: Moreover, since the molecule is completely conjugated(in fact cross conjugated), so only a partial negative charge would exist on the nitro group in the resonance hybrid, so it's hydration will be quite less to consider

Comment: Perhaps in alkaline water, the attack on the carbonyl carbon would be by OH- ion.